# How to resolve shared library file errors while compilation

Tags: c++, shared-library

I'm compiling my project using Makefile & I'm getting the following error.

```
[rahul@wbms-dev wdb]$ make
/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/bin/proc INCLUDE=/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/lib INCLUDE=/home/rahul/newest_wbms_code_071521/src/wut INCLUDE=/home/rahul/newest_wbms_code_071521/src/wbr CODE=ANSI_C LTYPE=NONE IRECLEN=256 SQLCHECK=FULL USERID=wbms/myPassword@myProjb iname=OrganizationModelDB.p
/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/bin/proc: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.19.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [OrganizationModelDB.c] Error 127
```

I have added the PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH & ORACLE_HOME in ~/.bashrc file.

```
PATH=$PATH:/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c
```

The libclntsh.so.19.1 file has required rwx permissions too.

```
[rahul@wbms-dev ~]$ ls -l /orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/lib/ | grep 'libclntsh*'
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        21 Jul  1 08:42 libclntshcore.so -> libclntshcore.so.19.1
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis   8040704 Jul  1 08:42 libclntshcore.so.19.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        17 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.19.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        12 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so.10.1 -> libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        12 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so.11.1 -> libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        12 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so.12.1 -> libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis        12 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so.18.1 -> libclntsh.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle mis  79942576 Jul  1 08:42 libclntsh.so.19.1
```

I'm unable to comprehend what the error is about & how to resolve it. Please help.

Comment: Is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` exported at any point?

Comment: I have added LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the ~/.bashrc file exactly as shown in the question.
Is it not sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want the linker to notice it, it will also need to be exported. I asked whether you did that manually, because it's obviously not done in your shell's startup-file.  If you _did_ do that manually, or elsewhere, then there's something else wrong, but I thought we'd just clear up the easy possible causes of your issue first.

Comment: I haven't done it manually. Please tell me how to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH. 

Is it just by executing the line "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c/lib" in bash?
If done like this, is it permanent or only for the session?

Comment: You could do it just for the session by just typing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the shell, but if you want to make it persistent, then use `export` in `~/.bashrc` _just like you did for `ORACLE_HOME`_.  The `PATH` variable is already an environment variable, so that does not need to be exported again.  Also, remember, I don't know for certain that this would solve your problem, but it would certainly be partway there.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda. Your suggestion worked like charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that you set in your `~/.bashrc` file never gets exported.  Since it's never exported, the linker will not see it.

To export the variable, which creates an environment variable from it which other commands that you start can see, you use the `export` command:

```bsh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may also export the variable at the same time as you set it, just like you've done with your `ORACLE_HOME` variable.  You could in fact write your three lines of variable assignments using your `$ORACLE_HOME` value like so:

```bsh
export ORACLE_HOME=/orasw/app/oracle/product/client_19c
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

This would reduce the amount of duplication and the number of places that you have to change the value whenever you update to a newer release of the Oracle tools.

The `PATH` variable does not need to be exported as it is already an environment variable.